# Changing colour of CGContextFillRect depending on size

Tags: ios, audio, cgcontext, visualizer

I am using the following code to show an audio visualizer, it basically shows 2 bars one for left input and one for right input, these work fine but i want to know if there is any way to change the colour of the rect so just the peak power will be red for instance while normal value will be still a green bar? here is my code.

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(15.0, 10.0, kMeterViewFullWidth * leftValue, 15.0));
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(15.0, 35.0, kMeterViewFullWidth * rightValue, 15.0));
} else {
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(15.0, 10.0, kMeterViewFullWidthiPad * leftValue, 15.0));
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(15.0, 35.0, kMeterViewFullWidthiPad * rightValue, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to do what i needed using the following code, there is a lot of if statements but it works, hope this will help anyone else that needs it

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
// Drawing code
[[UIColor greenColor] set];
[@"L" drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 10.0, 10.0, 15.0) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]] lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[@"R" drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 35.0, 10.0, 15.0) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]] lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];

CGRect tempLeftRect = CGRectMake(15, 10, kMeterViewFullWidth * leftValue, 15.0);
NSLog(@"%f", tempLeftRect.size.width);
CGRect tempRightRect = CGRectMake(15, 10, kMeterViewFullWidth * leftValue, 15.0);
NSLog(@"%f", tempRightRect.size.width);

if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 0) {
    [self firstLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 27) {
    [self secondLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 39) {
    [self thirdLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 51) {
    [self forthLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 63) {
    [self fitfhLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 75) {
    [self sixthLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 87) {
    [self seventhLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 99) {
    [self eigthLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 111) {
    [self ninthLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 123) {
    [self tenthLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 135) {
    [self eleventhLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 147) {
    [self twelthLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 159) {
    [self thirteenthLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 171) {
    [self forteenthLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 183) {
    [self fitfhteenthLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 195) {
    [self sixteenthLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 207) {
    [self seventeenthLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 219) {
    [self eighteenthLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 231) {
    [self nineteenthLeftBar];
}
if (tempLeftRect.size.width > 243) {
    [self twentyethLeftBar];
}

if (tempRightRect.size.width > 0) {
    [self firstRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 27) {
    [self secondRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 39) {
    [self thirdRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 51) {
    [self forthRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 63) {
    [self fitfhRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 75) {
    [self sixthRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 87) {
    [self seventhRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 99) {
    [self eigthRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 111) {
    [self ninthRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 123) {
    [self tenthRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 135) {
    [self eleventhRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 147) {
    [self twelthRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 159) {
    [self thirteenthRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 171) {
    [self forteenthRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 183) {
    [self fitfhteenthRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 195) {
    [self sixteenthRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 207) {
    [self seventeenthRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 219) {
    [self eighteenthRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 231) {
    [self nineteenthRightBar];
}
if (tempRightRect.size.width > 243) {
    [self twentyethRightBar];
}



/*
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(15.0, 10.0, kMeterViewFullWidth * leftValue, 15.0));
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(15.0, 35.0, kMeterViewFullWidth * rightValue, 15.0));
} else {
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(15.0, 10.0, kMeterViewFullWidthiPad * leftValue, 15.0));
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(15.0, 35.0, kMeterViewFullWidthiPad * rightValue, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
 */
}


- (void)updateMeterWithLeftValue:(CGFloat)left rightValue:(CGFloat)right {
leftValue = left;
rightValue = right;
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)firstLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(15.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)secondLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(27.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)thirdLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(39.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)forthLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(51.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)fitfhLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(63.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)sixthLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(75.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)seventhLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(87.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)eigthLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(99.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)ninthLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(111.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)tenthLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(123.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)eleventhLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(135.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)twelthLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(147.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)thirteenthLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(159.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)forteenthLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(171.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)fitfhteenthLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(183.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)sixteenthLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(195.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)seventeenthLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(207.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)eighteenthLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(219.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)nineteenthLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(231.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)twentyethLeftBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(243.0, 10.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)firstRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(15.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)secondRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(27.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)thirdRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(39.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)forthRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(51.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)fitfhRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(63.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)sixthRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(75.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)seventhRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(87.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)eigthRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(99.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)ninthRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(111.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)tenthRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(123.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)eleventhRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(135.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)twelthRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(147.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)thirteenthRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(159.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)forteenthRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(171.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)fitfhteenthRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(183.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)sixteenthRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(195.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)seventeenthRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(207.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)eighteenthRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(219.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)nineteenthRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(231.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}

-(void)twentyethRightBar{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(243.0, 35.0, 9.0, 15.0));
}
CGContextFlush(context);
}
```